# Laravel Vue js authentication middleware

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I creating web application with laravel as backend and vue as frontend (SPA). but for authentication I do not use `jwt auth` but instead use the normal laravel auth session. so when  the web was first loaded I put a global variable to access the user information in order to setup middleware.

Global user information.

```
<script>
    window.App = {
        config: @json($config),
        user: @json($currentUser)
    }
</script>
```

So in vue js I'm make middleware for auth like this.

Auth.js

```
export default (to, from, next) => {
  if (!window.App.user) {
    window.location.href = "/login";
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
```

Guest.js

```
export default (to, from, next) => {
  if (window.App.user) {
    next({ name: "home" });
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
```

In component I had to do like so.

```
Vue.prototype.$auth = window.App.user;
<template>

</template>

<script>
export default {
   methods: {
      post() {
        if (this.$auth) {
           // request to server
        }
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Is this good to implement authentication middleware like this? can the client modify `window.App.user`? can the client access the server just by modifying `window.App.user`? something like in the console

```
window.App.user = { id: 1, name: "Test" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this good to implement authentication middleware like this?

yes just improve its:

helper funcation:

```
export function isAuthenticated() {
   return window.App.user !== null; //or !== undefinded 
}
```

Auth.js

```
export default (to, from, next) => {
  //this tested using Vue Router 
   const publicPages = ['/login'];
   const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);
    
   if (authRequired && !isAuthenticated()) {
     next('/login'); //  or   window.location.href = "/login";
   }else{
     next('home');
   }
}
```

> can the client modify window.App.user?

yes every thing in client side is editable

> can the client access the server just by modifying window.App.user?

This is related to your server logic (middlewares)